# Expo Location don't working inside Expo Background Fetch

Tags: background-fetch

```
TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async () => {
  const now = Date.now();

  console.log(
    `Got background fetch call at date: ${new Date(now).toISOString()}`
  );

  let { status } = Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  console.log(status);
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
    return;
  }

  
    let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    console.log(coords);
  

  // Be sure to return the successful result type!
  return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;
});
```

When I use `let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({}); console.log(coords);`

Background Fetch don't work. How can I solve this?

When I use Backgroung Fetch with a `console.log('Any Text')` it works properly and it shows message every 1 minute. But if I use  `Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})` It don't show the result.